# How to list all untracked git files matching a certain pattern (and delete them)?

Tags: bash, git

In a Django project, I've run a `python manage.py compilescss` command which has generated a bunch of untracked CSS files:

[image]

I would like to delete all untracked files ending with `*css` with a single command. From [Git: list only "untracked" files (also, custom commands)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801321/git-list-only-untracked-files-also-custom-commands), I've so far found that the command to list all untracked files is

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

However, although it seems there is an `-x` (or `--exclude`) option to exclude files matching a certain pattern, there is no equivalent `--include` option to which I could pass `*css`.

Is there perhaps a generic Bash way to filter down these results to CSS files and then mass-delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by piping the result to `grep` (with a regular expression argument) and `xargs rm`:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard | grep -E "\.css$" | xargs rm
```

After running this command, the untracked CSS files have been removed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`git clean` is a very useful command to get rid of generated files. If the files are already ignored by Git, add the `-x` flag to include ignored files. Typically CSS files are contained in a very specific sub-tree of the project, and you can run `git clean -x path/to/Django/root/*/static`.

The `--dry-run` flag lists files to be deleted, and `--force` actually deletes them.

Comment: In my case, the CSS files are not contained in a single directory but are in the `static` directories of various Django apps, so I do need to match a pattern. It occurred to me that I could use the `--exclude` option if I can pass in a pattern meaning 'not ending with .css'; I tried `git clean --exclude '(?!.+\.css)'` but this didn't work.

Comment: Following up on my previous comment, I needed to pass in either `--dry-run` or `--force` as an additional argument to make it run. It seems, though, like the `pattern` expected needs to be a POSIX regular expression, which does not support lookaheads or lookbehinds (according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377469/posix-regular-expressions-excluding-a-word-in-an-expression).

Comment: You can specify several directories - I've amended to show this.

Comment: According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/, "static files should be stored in a folder called `static` in your app". So for a project with multiple apps, CSS files are in multiple folders. (After running the [`collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) command, they are also collected to the `STATIC_ROOT`, but they still remain in their app directories as well).